# Duplicate icons shows in taskbar corner overflow settings on Windows 11

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-11

As showed in the snapshot below, there are 2 dropbox and 2 wechat icons. I've tried several approaches including edit registry, but doesn't work.

How to fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***From [How to Clear Customize Notifications (Taskbar Corner Overflow) Icons](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/clear-customize-notifications-tray-items-windows-7-vista-xp/)***

- Download the [clear_notification_taskbar_overflow_icons.vbs](https://gist.github.com/winhelponline/2587aaa1d2b32c61124f4c6f0d4eac67/raw/0649e831bd71e8b11924410aa3671d0496d100d3/clear_notification_taskbar_overflow_icons.vbs)
  script that will clear the Taskbar overflow icons.

**To reset the items manually:**

1. Start `regedit.exe`
2. In the Registry Editor, go to the following branch:

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`
3. Delete the two values, namely `IconStreams` and `PastIconsStream`
4. Exit the Registry Editor.
5. Launch Task Manager. In the Processes tab, right-click `Windows Explorer` and click `Restart.`

**Note:** The above methods clear **both** current as well as obsolete icons shown in the Taskbar Corner Overflow settings page. There is no option to clear the items selectively.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: @migrant Have you tried the script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the PromotedIconCache key as well (delete everything under TrayNotify except the default key)